# Room response full error in AppRTC and How to clear id or url after disconnecting a call?

Tags: apprtc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOHYN.png)Having an issue of room full, while again connecting call from same URL.
I am getting an error of Hung up , i am using Android Studio

Comment: can you show us the error and the code please ?

Comment: https://github.com/deano2390/AppRTC link of code